# Getting a movie's gross revenue trend

Tags: box-office

<sub>I am new to this site, so not sure if this kind of question will be considered as on topic or not. But here goes</sub>

Is there a way to get a movie's revenue trend since it is released (either worldwide or in certain regions). I am interested in newer movies only, so don't worry if the database does not extend beyond 2012.

I searched a lot and finally found [Box Office Mojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com) which gives per day box office revenue of a movie. But it only considers US Box Office revenue and not Gross Worldwide Revenue.

Since we would find many movie fans here, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on my other answer, it seems like you're after a website like http://www.the-numbers.com/. This has breakdowns of revenue in a graph and table.

It also includes stats on domestic, internation, and worldwide revenue at the top of each movie profile.

[image]

Comment: Again, this is equivalent to boxofficemojo.com which gives daily stat on US Box Office along with a summary of worldwide revenue as well.